# Redis: Getting JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool When connecting to remote server

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am trying to connect from a Java App running on Windows 10 using Jedis client to a remote Redis instance. My program fails with exception JedisConnectionException.

**Environment**

1. Redis version 5.x running on Ubuntu 19.04 in a VM
2. Redis is configured to listen on a specific IP with a password and with protected mode set to on/yes.
3. I am running my dev environment on a Windows 10 Pro machine.
4. Jedis version is 3.1.0
5. JDK is OpenJDK 11.0.4 on both Windows & Linux.

**What I have tried**

1. I have tested connecting to the remote (running on VM) Redis server using local redis-cli and was successful, confirming that I am able to access, connect and use the redis-server.
2. I ran my test program from Netbeans 11.1 IDE running on another Linux VM on the same host with different IP and that was also a success.
3. I ran my test program (100% same code) from Netbeans 11.1 IDE running on the host Windows 10 machine and the program failed to connect and threw the exception.

**Code Snippet**

pool = new JedisPool(
                    config, 
                    "192.168.199.130", 6379, 
                    Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,"foobar",
                    Protocol.DEFAULT_DATABASE);
Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();  // this statement throws the exception
jedis.close();

**Summary**

JedisPool.getResource() works on Linux while same code fails from Windows.

Did anyone else run into this?

Any and all help appreciated.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do have the issue resolved. Strangely I was able to connect from redis-cli but not from the Jedis api. Playing with the config on the redis server resolved this issue. – Tutan just now

Comment: Could you provide what did you change in the config ?